# Why has word indented this sentence and how can I remove it?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

If I put a new line after the comma, it turns it into a paragraph:

[image]

Comment: You can go to View tab, turn on the Ruler, and then drag the indentation back to where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Try using Shift and Enter at an appropriate spot in the line to see if that helps. It often works for me.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, @QuickishFM the ruler fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why has word indented this sentence and how can I remove it?

You have what is called a [hanging indent](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hanging_indent.html).

To remove it:

> 1. Select the text where you want to remove a hanging indent.
> 2. Go to Home > Paragraph dialog launcher [image] > Indents and Spacing.
> 3. Under Special, select None.
>
>    [image: Selecting None for indent]
> 4. Select OK.

Source [Remove or clear a hanging indent - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/remove-or-clear-a-hanging-indent-5e603ba9-6ac9-41f8-8b3a-25ee538123b6)